# What species is Maz Kanata?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Around halfway through *The Force Awakens*, the gang meet up with Maz Kanata, an orange colored seer who claims to be able to tell people by their eyes.

What species was she?

Comment: Hm, interesting. Her species isn't mentioned in her Wookieepedia article.

Comment: Pirate. Her species is **space pirate**. ARRRR!

Comment: I'd really describe her as more *salmon* than orange.

Comment: She is probably play Yoda.. There's always an old and wise person whose background details are made confidential by writers.

Comment: Her hands look quite different from Yoda's. Not likely to be the same species.

Comment: Tell people what?

Comment: Maz Kantata! What a wonderful phrase!

Comment: According to the new (and updated) Character Encyclopedia, her homeworld is Takonada. That could indicate that she's *Takonadan* or it could just be them mis-using the word 'homeworld' to mean 'world that she lives on'.

Answer (score 12):

This piece of information is deliberately left out of currently available materials. We don't know and we won't know in near future.

> In the movie, you don’t learn these things *[her species and homeworld - insertion mine]*, but I know that these are things that are coming out in other venues.
>   J.J. Abrams - [source](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/11/12/star-wars-force-awakens-lupita-nyongo-maz-kanata)

Comment: This doesn't belong to an answer, but there are some parallels between her and Yoda (longevity, short height, special powers). Since Canon features only a handful of Yoda species characters, we can't say anything about  in-species variation (for all we know, Twi'leks and humans come in different colors, so maybe that species does as well). It's anyone's guess if she is from the same species or planet as Yoda.

Comment: I feel plot-wise, Maz Kanata is meant to take the role that Yoda had. An ancient, wise, Force-sensitive, but nonetheless secondary mentor figure. And like Yoda, her origins are deliberately unrevealed.

Comment: It would be somewhat interesting if she were the same species as Yoda, and they just had [sexual dimorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_dimorphism).

Comment: @T.D.L. We have already seen a female of Yoda's species, Yaddle, one of the other Jedi Council members in Episode 1.

Answer (score -2):

- [Dressellian](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dressellian)
- [Kumumgah](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kumumgah)

Both look possible to me... Though it is true that the sources for the Kumumgah are all now categorized as "Legends" and the Dressellian canon data is far from complete. I don't see any reason why Disney would not reinstate or expand species developed in the legends, just under their own terms.
For example The Legends data says that Dressellians where quite tall but this is not necessarily true for the canon. 
Many species also shrink with age so that could also be a factor.
Maz species not being mentioned is not actually that unusual as the canon materials quite often avoid confronting that question directly on first meeting a character.

Comment: This is not a solid answer. I recommend you take our [tour] to see what kind of answers we are looking for.

Answer (score -3):

Possibly Kumumgah? They could be the ancestors of both the sand people and the Jawas, which would explain both her pirate and hoarding sides.

Is there any evidence in canon supporting this?

As far as I can find, no. I'm just making speculations based on her appearance and personality traits as:

1. She's short, like a Jawa.
2. She also wears goggles, like a Tusken.
3. She's a hoarder, and was a "space pirate".

The only visual representation of Kumumgah I could find was this:

[image]

It's a stretch, but could be a fit.

There is also this, which was in Anakins room on Tatooine (the Kumumgahs home planet):

[image]